# C#: if else statement with listView

Tags: c#, forms, listview, if-statement

what i am trying to do is check if the listView (column5) contains ANY items with the word 'Yes'. If it does write 'Great', if the column does not contain any items at ALL with the word 'Yes' write 'Bad'.

Whats happening now is my program is only writing Bad (the else statement) even if the column does contain an item that has the word 'Yes'.

How can I fix this?:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items) {
    if (item.SubItems[5].Text.Contains("Yes")) {
        // Do your work here
        labelContainsVideo2.Text = "GREAT";
        labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    } else {
        labelContainsVideo2.Text = "BAD";
        labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some data, that you are using?

Comment: Are you conscious that the only `item` that will count is the last one?

Comment: Have you checked that this operation is performed after Data is bound ?

Comment: Make it easy on yourself to debug this by changing the lines that set the text to:

labelContainsVideo2.Text = item.SubItems[5].Text;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last item in your list doesn't contain "Yes", then the output will be "BAD", regardless of what the other items contain.

Try this instead...

```
string message = "BAD";
var msgColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    if (item.SubItems[5].Text.Contains("Yes"))
    {
        message = "GREAT";
        msgColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        break;   // no need to check any more items - we have a match!
    }
}
labelContainsVideo2.Text = message ;
labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = msgColor;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe for the case?

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
  if (item.SubItems[5].Text.ToUpper().Contains("YES"))
  {
    // Do your work here
    labelContainsVideo2.Text = "GREAT";
    labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
  }
  else
  {
    labelContainsVideo2.Text = "BAD";
    labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Also, have in mind that this way it will only count the last `item`. If you want to show all items state you should have a labels array or something. If what you want is to know if **any** items contains 'Yes', you should follow @ZombieSheep answer.

Comment: As I'm converting the text to uppercase, it should be searching for 'YES', not 'Yes'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(i => i.SubItems[5].Text.ToLower().Contains("yes"))){
    labelContainsVideo2.Text = "GREAT";
    labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
else
{
    labelContainsVideo2.Text = "BAD";
    labelContainsVideo2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```